# Integration of an unnormalized sinc function in an interval

Tags: integration, signal-processing

I have been working on getting an analytical equation for a scalar potential of a source function in an elastic wave equation, in which I end up with an expression that has an integration of unnormalized $Sinc$ function in an interval as:

$\int\limits_{-\pi a}^{\pi a} Sinc(x\:k) \:dk$

here $a$ is a constant and $x$ is a spatial domain and $k$ is corresponding spatial frequency (Wavenumber). I know the integration of $Sinc$ function is $\pi$ in the integral between $-\infty$  and $\infty$. But I don't know how to integrate $Sinc$ in an interval between $-\pi a$ and  $\pi a$.

Anyway I did try to simplify the integration as follows.

$2\:\int\limits_{0}^{\pi a} Sinc(x\:k) \:dk$

$2\:Si(\pi a)$ $\;$ where $Si$ is a sine integral.

I just wanted to know if I am right, if not please help me to simplify the integration. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are almost correct:  $\frac{\text{Si}(a \pi  x)+\text{Si}(x \text{$\pi $a})}{x}$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
So, do you mean:   $2\: \int_{0}^{\pi a} Sinc(xk) \: dk = \frac{Si(a\:\pi\:x)+Si(a\:\pi\:x)}{x}\:=2\: \frac{Si(a\:\pi\:x)}{x}$.

Right?

Comment: Yes.... that's what *Mathematica* gives.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will make use of your comment.